# Need some advice on CLI design, I need to provide simple but powerful command line options

Tags: user-interface, interfaces, software, unix, utilities

I am writing a utility that runs on RHEL5 command line. I need my command line options to be simple but powerful. I looked at the various UNIX utilities to get an idea of how simple  command line utilities have to be. Do you guys suggest any documents/links that talk about command line etiquette? I am modelling my utility on top of LVM (that's all the info I can give for now). I know it's a software engineering question, but I thought it would be appropriate to post here. Please advise....

PS: I am not asking for details about getopt or command line utility parsers.....

Answer (score 5):

`<what> <how> <which>`

`<what>`: what you want to do. If your software does lots of different things, you might want to use different commands or command/subcommand (e.g. `git pull`, `git push`, etc.)

`<how>`: modifiers on what you want to do. Typically one switches/command-taking options (e.g. `-s`, `-s <arg>`). Most often used commands deserve one character identifiers- probably all commands should get long names (e.g. `--short`). `-v`/`--verbose`, `-d`/`--debug`, `-n`/`--dry-run`, `-o`/`--out`, `-h`/`--help`, `-V`/`--version`... there are quite a few commands which are somewhat standardized

`<which>` files/stuff are you operating on. `-` meaning stdin (or no args) should be provided if possible.

Interesting stuff:

- If your command spits output, provide an option to generate machine-readable output
- Use stdout/stderr correctly
- Provide shell completion hooks
- Provide man pages

Answer (score 1):

You have started with:

```
need my command line options to be simple but powerful
```

```
modelling my utility on top of LVM(thats all the info I can give for now)
```

Good thing that's not a tall-order request.

Since we don't know what specific logical volume manager functions you are referring to, it's hard to give specific examples of what to create for a command line option.

In general, you want to think about:
- commonly performed tasks
- steps required to perform those tasks
- how to simplify the steps and the tasks into single element

"Simple" is actually much more difficult to code.  You will likely need to eliminate the hundreds of options that *could be* and focus on the ones that are *needed.*

To rephrase what you're asking for is this: **non-trivial** and **easy to use**.  Dig into your use cases; find the commonality; present a "single" option to reflect the commonality of that use case.

And / Or just write really solid documentation that thoroughly explains what the options will do.  One fault I find with most man pages is that they're usually great for reference, but difficult to learn from.